# What does this command 'xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app' do?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native

I had a problem installing cocoapods `flipper-glog` so found out this solution to run:
this command `xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`.
But what does this command actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Many command-line tools require access to functionality that is actually hidden inside Xcode itself. `xcode-select` points to the copy of Xcode where that functionality is located.

If you say in the Terminal

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin; ls
```

you will see some of the tools in question. For instance, if a cocoa pod needs to compile some code, it needs `gcc` which is located inside that directory within Xcode. Similarly `make` is in there (that's probably the main thing that `flipper-glog` needed).